# Swapping data of a Binary

Tags: sed, awk, swap

I just want to swap the first 64 characters of a file with the last 64 characters of the same binary file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to process a binary file with text-oriented tools?

Comment: If it's a binary file, I'd say you're more likely to want to swap 64 bytes than 64 characters. (We live in a Unicode world. Don't assume 1 char = 1 byte.) And, like @belisarius said, text utils are, at best, a risky choice for dealing with binary files. Is this homework?

Comment: I'm tempted to say something about just loading it into vim in vim's notorious "corrupt" mode, but I won't. Oops.

Comment: @Catcall That was the right choice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done reliably with sed or awk. I can imagine a solution that would work on a specific file, or with certain odd conditions like where newlines might appear.

This is fairly easy to do in C. And if not restricted to sed or awk, it can be done with shell commands, too:

```
n=64
f=/tmp/test
eval $(stat -s $f)
e=$(($st_size - $n))
dd bs=1  count=$n if=$f          iseek=$e of=/tmp/last64
dd bs=$n count=1  if=$f                   of=/tmp/first64
dd bs=1  count=$n if=/tmp/first64 seek=$e of=$f conv=notrunc
dd bs=$n count=1  if=/tmp/last64          of=$f conv=notrunc
```

Comment: Your solution work for me.  But I want to know that   1. bs=1 count=64 and count=64 bs=1   is same or different.   After re-swapping the 64-bytes, ( retaining the original binary ), I observed that md5sum values differs. Why is so behavior ?

Comment: `stat -s` seems to be a BSD option. GNU doesn't seem to have it. `st_size=$(wc -c < $f)` can probably be used instead.

Comment: stat -c %s is the option that we can use.

Comment: Cross-Verification: Does not matter, what you use, [ bs=1 count=64 ] or [ bs=64 count=1 ], it is one-and-same.  Md5sum also retains. ANd for XXD solution, I guess, same thing can be achieved by using hexdump with -r and -p option. Thnx again.

Comment: Oh, heh, sorry. I like the bsdish flavor of my Mac but I see it caused some confusion here. BTW, you can't replace `bs=1 count=64` because then there is no way (that I could think of) to seek to the beginning of the final 64 bytes. I get the same md5 after running the script twice, so I think it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xxd`:

```
n=64
file=data
tmp=tmp
len=$(wc -c < "$file")
offset=$((len - n))
len=$((offset - n))
xxd -s -$n "$file" | xxd -r -s -$offset > "$tmp"
xxd -s $n -l $len "$file" | xxd -r  >> "$tmp"
xxd -l $n "$file" | xxd -r >> "$tmp"
mv "$tmp" "$file"
```

**Edit:**

Another approach would be to use `xxd` and `sed`:

```
n=64; hd=$((n * 2))
file=data
tmp=tmp
xxd -c $n -p "$file" |
    sed "1{x;d};:a;N;s/\n//;\${s/\(.*\)\(.\{$hd\}\)\$/\2\1/;G};ba" | 
    xxd -r -p > "$tmp"
mv "$tmp" "$file"
```

Instead of six calls to `xxd`, it's two to `xxd` and one to `sed` (and fewer file reads and writes, too).

Explanation of the `sed` command:

- `1{x;d}` - Save the first line of hex digits in hold space. The length of the line is set to the number of bytes to swap using the `-c` option of `xxd`.
- `:a` - Label "a"

  - `N` - Append the next line.
  - `s/\n//` - Remove the embedded newline
  - `\${` - If it's the last line of input:

    - `s/\(.*\)\(.\{$hd\}\)\$/\2\1/` - Swap the last `$hd` bytes to the beginning
    - `G` - Append the first `$n` bytes from hold space onto the end. Since it's the last line, the script ends.
  - `}` - end if
- `ba` - Branch to label "a".

Additionally, `sed` could do some manipulation of the data.